# Entity Framework specify cardinality in a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

We have a many-to-many relationship, which we specify fluently like this:

```
Hasmay(A=>A.Bs).WithMany(B.As)
```

An "A" can have zero or more "B"'s.
An "B" must have one or more "A"'s.

Is there a way to specify the cardinality for the "As" in "B"?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't specify a 1-n relationship, it's always 0-n with code first. You'll have to manage the 1 at the application level (or add a constraint in base with raw sql).

Comment: You can do it the same way you would in SQL: B.AId should be a Non-NULL field

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: can't find it my self either hence the post. If no one has a solution, we will probably implement it as a business rule and leave raw sql on the database out of it. Bad part is that will require a an "Any" check in each validation cycle

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: There is no B.AId in B. The AId lives in the join table for AsBs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos B.Aid doesn't exist. A relational table will be created at sql level (but doesn't appear as an entity object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because under the hood it's a 1-n-1 association. That is, `A` has zero, one, or many `AB` junction records, and `AB` always has one `B` (and always one `A`).

So we're dealing with the rules of 1-n associations. There is no way to enforce a 1 - **1**..n association (i.e. a parent must have at least one child), at least not in DDL. Consequently there is no way to enforce 1..n - 1..m associations. It's always 0..n - 0..m. Only by business logic you can enforce mandatory associations.